# Showing a Sequence of Subsets of $\Bbb Q$ Tends to a Dense Subset of $\left[0,\infty\right)$

Tags: number-theory, rational-numbers

For $N\in\mathbb{N}$, let:

$S_{N}=\left\{ \left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^{N},\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^{N}\times6,\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^{N}\times6^{2},...,\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^{N}\times6^{2N}\right\}$

I suspect that, as $N\rightarrow\infty$, $S_{N}$ tends to a dense subset of $[0,\infty)$. How would one go about (dis)proving this?

Addendum:

Consider a sequence $\left\{ s_{N}\right\} _{N\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that for each $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $s_{N}\in S_{N}$. Do there exist such sequences which converge to 1 as $N\rightarrow\infty$? And what can be said about the set of the limits of all such sequences?

Comment: I say that $S_N \to \{0\}$.

Comment: Since $S_N\cap S_M$ is empty when $N\ne M,$ in what sense can you say that the the sequence $(S_N)_N$ "tends" to anything?

Comment: I suppose I should add that my ultimate goal would be to characterize the limiting behavior of sequences of the form $\left\{ s_{N}\right\} _{N\in\mathbb{N}}$ where, for each $N$, $s_{N}\in S_{N}$. In particular, I want to know when and how such an $s_{N}$ would tend to 1.

Answer (score 0):

The gap in the sequence is about the same as the last element, so none of the $S_N$ are dense away from a neighborhood of zero. Their *union*, however does become dense.

Comment: I guess you should mention that $\log_6\frac{9}{2}$ is an irrational number. Also I don't think "the closest you can get to an integer for a fixed $N$ and $x$ is around $1/N$", rather, it should be that because the fractional parts of $\log_6 x+N\log_6\frac{9}{2}$ for all natural numbers $N$ are dense in $(0,1)$, thus  $\log_6 x+N\log_6\frac{9}{2}$ is arbitrarily close to a natural number.

Comment: @shrinklemma No, what you say at the end is not good enough. You don't want the union of all $S_N$ to be dense, but each one become more dense.

Comment: I see. Well, then the sequence is not dense, since the gap between the last two numbers in $S_N$ is bigger than 1.

Comment: @shrinklemma The OP is not asking about any one of the $S_N.$ Anyway, my answer was to a wrong question, but fixed now.

Comment: It *isn't* dense? Marvelous! What then might the closure of the limit be? And are there any accumulation points?

Comment: Notice that if the $k$-th element of $S_N$ (for any $N$) is bigger than $a,$ the gap between it and the previous element is $5/6 a.$ Which means that the only accumulation point is $0.$ Again, the union of the $S_N$ *is* dense.

Comment: What about sequences $\left\{ s_{N}\right\} _{N\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that for each $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $s_{N}\in S_{N}$. Do any of them converge to 1 as $N\rightarrow\infty$? And what is the structure of the set of the limits of all such sequences?

Comment: @MCS What do you mean by "converge to $1?$

Comment: You have a sequence of *sets* of real numbers, and then construct a sequence of *numbers* by picking one number from the first set, one number from the second set, and so on and so forth. Using this construction on the $S_{N}$s, can you ever get a sequence of numbers which converges (in euclidean distance) to 1 (i.e. $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}s_{N}=1$)?

Comment: @MCS yes, you can.

Comment: Is there an algorithm for how to construct such sequences?

Comment: Yes, it's basically the continued fraction algorithm.

Comment: Can you give me the details—or a link to a pertinent source?

Comment: @MCS Let's stick with $1.$ You would like $(2/9)^N 6^k$ to be close to $1.$ This means that $\log_6((2/9)^N 6^k)$ is close to $0.$ So,$N  \log_6 (2/9) + k$ is close to $0.$ In other words, you want a good rational approximation to $(\log 9 - \log 2)/(\log 6).$ Continued fractions are then your friend (and the same method works for any fixed $x$ instead of $1.)$

Comment: Got it. Thanks a bunch!